# Holdout loss much worse than training & testing data

Tags: regression, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a simple MLP which is to predict a single output based and 9 inputs.

The data is scaled between 0 and 1, and the data is shuffled before training.
The resulting model leads to very low loss, both for validation and training. (0.005 mean squared error for both).

However, I also have a holdout dataset that is not part of the training process at all. When i try to predict on this dataset, the results are much worse.

I used the same scaler for this data, as I save the min-max scaler used during training.

I know one of the problems can be that the data is not comparable to the training data, i.e there is a different "behaviour" in the holdout data, but i have carefully examined that datasets, and cannot see any such behaviour.

What else can be the source of such a problem?

In the picture below you can see the original target value in blue, and the predicted value in orange.

Note that this is the complete dataset:

Holdout : sample 0 to ~90K

Test/Training : sample ~90K to end

[image: prediction on holdout and train/test]

Comment: This definitely looks like a problem with different preprocessing of the data

Comment: That's what i thought as well, but I have double checked that I am using the same scaler.

Originally i was training the model in one script, then saved the scaler & model. 
Then i loaded both in another script to do inference on my holdout set.

However, to be completely sure that I didnt do anythin wrong here I loaded both the training set AND the holdout set in the same script and used scaler.fit_transform on the traning data and scaler.transform on the holdout data.

Comment: Question: is the data a time series/is treated like one? Or are these samples treated independently.

Comment: Individually, there are no time that in the system, so I'm not using RNN, just a normal dense network